# How require() works when requiring the same module in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

When a module is required in node.js more than once it gives back the same object because `require()` cache the previous calls.

Lets say I have a main logger module what could register the sub logger modules. (Those make the logging actually through the main logger module `log()` function. But its not related here.)

I have something like this in the main logger module to add a sub-module:

```
module.addRedisLogger = function(rclient) {
     modulesArray.push(require('./redis.js')(rclient, loggingEnabled, module));
}
```

When I create a redis client instance, I could immediately add a logger to it like this:

```
var sub = redis.createClient();
logger.addRedisLogger(sub);
```

In the sub module I start to log like this:

```
module.startLogging = function() {
    rclient.on("message", messageCallback);
    rclient.on("pmessage", pmessageCallback);
}
```

And stop logging like this:

```
module.stopLogging = function() {
    rclient.removeListener("message", messageCallback);
    rclient.removeListener("pmessage", pmessageCallback);

}
```

But as far as I understand, with this technique I could only assign one redis logger instance because assigning the second one would return in the `require()` with the same object as in the first, so passing the new `redis` parameter would override the previous value. Because of that it would not be possible to stop the logging in the first redis logger instance because calling it, would stop the logging in the second instance.

Lets see an example:

```
var sub1 = redis.createClient();
var sub2 = redis.createClient();

sub1.subscribe("joinScreen1");
sub2.subscribe("joinScreen2");

logger.addRedisLogger(sub1);
logger.addRedisLogger(sub2);

// running redis-cli PUBLISH joinScreen1 message1
// running redis-cli PUBLISH joinScreen2 message2

logger.log("Lets stop the first logger);
logger.modulesArray[0].stopLogging()

// running redis-cli PUBLISH joinScreen1 message1
// running redis-cli PUBLISH joinScreen2 message2
```

I except to get this output:

```
// Message received on channel joinScreen1: message1
// Message received on channel joinScreen2: message2
// Message received on channel joinScreen1: message1
```

We should get this because the first logger now points to the second instance. So the `redis` points to the second client too.

But instead I get this:

```
// Message received on channel joinScreen1: message1
// Message received on channel joinScreen2: message2
// Message received on channel joinScreen2: message2
```

So it works as expected by PROGRAM DESIGN but not as expected by CODE. So I want to make it works as it works now, but I don't understand why it works like that.

**UPDATE:**

**Long Version**

*module.js*

```
var util = require("util");

module.exports = function () {
var module = {};

    module.show = function() {
        console.log(util.client);
    }

    module.set = function(value) {
        util.client= value;
    }

    return module;
};
```

*main.js*

```
var util = require("util");
util.client = "waaaa";

 var obj = require('./module')();

 obj.show();
 obj.set("weeee");

console.log(util.client);
```

Running the `main.js` will result this output:

```
C:\Users\me\Desktop>node main.js
waaaa
weeee
```

So `require()` gives back the very same object as the first time. If I changed it since then, then the changes are there too, because it is the same object.

Now lets say the variable `redis` is the same as `client` here and hold a reference to a redis connection. When the constructor runs the second time it  overrides the first one, that is why I except to get the notifications from the logger of the first redis client, because there is no reference pointing at it, so the listener couldn't be removed.

Comment: I'm having a hard time deciphering a question out of the post content. The question in the title is likely a duplicate, but i don't think that's what you're asking, you seem to already know how require() works and caches. In the end this is going to be a logic problem, and the logic (code) isn't organized in the post in a way that we can easily follow it (too much is missing).

Comment: I updated my question, I hope it is more understandable now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you say this:

> But as far as I understand, with this technique I could only assign one redis logger instance because assigning the second one would return in the require() with the same object as in the first, so passing the new redis parameter would override the previous value.

that is not what is happening in your case.  Your module is exporting a single function:

```
module.exports = function (rclient, ploggingEnabled, logger) {
```

Calling `require('./redis.js')` more than once will return this function each time.  That's true.  And if you modify properties of that function, then `require()` it again, you will indeed see the modifications you made:

```
(require('./redis.js')).x = "waaa";
console.log((require('./redis.js')).x); // "waaa"
```

But when you actually invoke the function instead of modifying its properties, something different happens: a [closure](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-closures-with-ease/) is created by declaring the `startLogging()` and `stopLogging()` functions, each of which manipulate variables higher up in the [scope chain](http://davidshariff.com/blog/what-is-the-execution-context-in-javascript/).  This means that every time you call this exported function, a new closure is created with its own private pointers to `rclient` and `ploggingEnabled` and `logger`.  If you save a reference to the value returned by this function (which you do, by `push()`ing it onto `modulesArray`) then you should be able to access each of those closures at a later time and perform whatever cleanup you need:

```
modulesArray.forEach(function(el, idx, arr) {
  el.stopLogging();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Like you said, require caches the RETURNED object of the `require` call. Take a look in your use case, where require is simply returning a `function` object, that's all. This function, when called, mutates some reference in memory, hence it works as expected. Caching a function, is not the same as caching the output of that function's call. In addition, returning a constructor function is the idiomatic way in node to expose classes, as every time you need a new object you can simply call the function. In other words, what you're doing is perfectly fine.

ex.

Case A

```
module.exports = new Date();
```

Case B

```
module.exports = function() {
  return new Date();
}
```

In case A, require will cache the date object, and will always return a reference to the same one. In case B, require will cache the function object, and will always return a reference to the same one. The difference is that in B, when calling that cached function, the function will return a new Date object each time.

Comment: I updated my question, and I need some clarification on your answer. I get it that if I export it as a function it will run everytime, but it still give me back the samb object right? so doing this,
     `var module = request("module");
     module.x = "y";
     console.log(request("module").x);`

will result printing the "y" to the console right? I want to get a new object, what doesn't have the defined x parameter.

Comment: That is correct, it should print "y".  Why do you think it should equal anything else? The variable `module` is a pointer to `request("module")`, so when you change property `x`, it would inevitably propogate that change to `request("module")`, as both are pointers to the EXACT same object.

Comment: Yes, but I do the very same in my real example and I am getting a different result. See the updated part (long version) of my question.

Comment: No, the result you are getting is completely consistent. In both modules you are calling `require('util")`, which means that in BOTH modules you will get the EXACT same object.  In `main.js` you are setting `require('util').client` to "waa", then you are calling `module.js` constructor, and using the `set` method to set `require('util').client` to "wee". You are mutating the EXACT same object, as `require('util')` is returning you the same reference in both `main.js` and `module.js`. I don't see anything that is inconsistent here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am talking from the real code sample what is included in my question not here, see update 2 for more detail.

Comment: @NoNameProvided I can't answer your question, because I don't understand what the problem is. In crystal clear terms, please describe what happens AFTER you call `logger.modulesArray[0].stopLogging()`, and what you THINK should happen instead. The output that you display is confusing, and it's too hard to understand what is going on. I would assume it should stop logging message #1, and continue logging message #2, no? Isn't that what is happening? If not, then what is happening?