# Nodejs require module behaviour

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to require a custom module in nodejs in multiple files. Will each require create a new instance of the module or the same instance gets shared among all the files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How require() works when requiring the same module in node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32588854/how-require-works-when-requiring-the-same-module-in-node-js)

Answer (score 1):

Per [doc](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html)

> Modules are cached after the first time they are loaded. This means (among other things) that every call to `require('foo')` will get exactly the same object returned, if it would resolve to the same file.
>
> Multiple calls to `require('foo')` may not cause the module code to be executed multiple times. This is an important feature. With it, "partially done" objects can be returned, thus allowing transitive dependencies to be loaded even when they would cause cycles.

Comment: If we change the value of a variable of foo in one of the file where we import will it be reflected across all the other files?

Comment: @AbinayaSadhasivam, if the reqire file is changed, I am afraid it will NOT be reflected across all other file, you can test it...